# How to convert a ns1.MyPersonalClass into ns2.MyPersonalClass ? They have same property or members

Tags: xml, vb.net, generics, namespaces

I have a problem.

Suppose I have two class, they have same name, same property, same members, etc. but NOT the same namespace. Here's an example:

```
Namespace ns1
    Public Class MyOwnClass

        Public member1 As Integer = 3
        Public member2 As String = "noob"

    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace ns2
    Public Class MyOwnClass

        Public member1 As Integer = 0
        Public member2 As String = ""

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I want to create a function where it will dynamically cast the class from the namespace1 to the namespace2, and I want this function to work on every class that have same members.

How to do this ?

I want something that I can use like this:

```
Dim class1 as new ns1.MyPersonalClass
Dim class2 as new ns2.MyPersonalClass

'Convert the class1 into class2
Convert(class1, class1.GetType, class2, class2.GetType)
```

The equivalent in C# is this

```
TOutput ConvertEquivalentTypes<TInput, TOutput>(TInput structure)
    where TInput : class
    where TOutput : class
{
    TOutput result = null;

    using (Stream data = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(TInput)).Serialize(data, structure);
        data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        result = (TOutput)new XmlSerializer(typeof(TOutput)).Deserialize(data);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: they dont have the same properties (in fact both have Fields not Properties) they just have the same Class name.  If the Fields are equivalents, you could create one from the other in the constructor.  How does XML play onto this?

Comment: Sorry, watch again, I changed the initial post, I did a mistake while posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET equivalent of C# code you currently have would be something like this:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
'...

Private Function ConvertEquivalentTypes(Of TInput As Class,
                              TOutput As Class)([structure] As TInput) As TOutput
  Dim result As TOutput = Nothing

  Using data As Stream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim oSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(TInput))
    oSerializer.Serialize(data, [structure])
    data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

    Dim oDeserializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(TOutput))
    result = DirectCast(oDeserializer.Deserialize(data), TOutput)
  End Using

  Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that was EXACTLY what I was searching for !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex the classes are, you can also create one from the other:

```vb
' ns1 version would be the same - omitted for brevity
Namespace ns2

    Public Class Class1
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Foo As Integer

        Public Sub New(c As ns1.Class1)
            Name = c.Name
            Foo = c.Foo
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

If there are lots of properties to transfer, the serializer might be more efficient, but neither method "converts" the classes, but creates a new instance from the other.  Here, we use the overloaded constructor to essentially copy the property values:

```
Dim c1 As New ns1.Class1
c1.Name = "ziggy"
Dim c2 As New ns2.Class1(c1)
```

Yet another way is to avoid the problem altogether.  Define the class once and simply `Import` that namespace wherever it is needed.

```vb
' new NS where the class is defined
Imports AppInstancer.ns0

Namespace ns1

    Public Class classA
        ' stub to create a Class1 object in NS1, but as
        ' a ns0 Type
        Public Shared Function GetNS1Object() As Class1
            Return New Class1
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now, the object can be converted because there is only one Type; it is simply consumed in different namespaces

```vb
' c1 created in ns1 namespace
Dim c1 As Class1 = ns1.classA.GetNS1Object
c1.Name = "ziggy"

' c2 created elsewhere, can convert:
Dim c2 As Class1 = CType(c1, Class1)
```

Another benefit is that there is no chance of the 2 classes getting out of sync property-wise.